# Can not recognise ttyACM usb modem

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g

I'm trying to use usb 3g modem, the problem is, that on one machine it connects to ttyACM instead of ttyUSB (it's being recognised successfully on other PCs).
I've created symlink to it:

```
ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And everything worked fine, I've managed to connect to internet, but only until first reboot. 
I've recreated link and tried to change permission and owner on it, but it didn't help - dmesg | grep ttyUSB returns nothing, while lsusb is listing modem as connected. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The link that you created in /dev disappears on reboot.

Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your `ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyUSB0` command at the end, and it'll survive reboots.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```